# How to get a variable from Ajax with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Underneath i have added my ajax script named checkMessages.php:

```
$user = $system->getUserInfo($_SESSION['user_id']);

$checkmes = $db->query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE receiver_id='".$user."' AND sent='0'");
$checkmes = $checkmes->fetch_object();

if(!empty($checkmes)) {
    $checkmes = true;
} else{
    $checkmes = false;
}
```

And also the javascript im trying to create:

```
function checkMessages() {
            $.get("'.$system->getDomain().'/ajax/checkMessages.php, function(data){
        $checkmes });
        if $checkmes == true {
                refreshChat();

            }
        }

            window.setInterval(function(){
  checkMessages();
}, 1000);
```

What i am trying to do is the following. checkMessages.php checks if there is a new message and i have made a setinterval to execute the function `checkMessages()` and call the ajax script every second.

So if there is a new message, the variable `$checkmes` is set to true. And if it is true, javascript should execute a different function, `refreshChat()`.

But my question is, how can i get the variable $checkmes from checkMessages.php with javascript, have it read if it is true?

I have been searching high and low but i have no idea. I've recently started to learn about coding so i hope someone can teach me how to do this. I would like to thank everybody who helps out beforehand.

Comment: You forgot a quote somewhere.

Comment: And start with understanding basic differences between server and client.

Comment: @u_mulder thank you for pointing this out. If i am right, ajax is server side and javascript client side. I thought if i would run a setinterval, javascript could read a variable from the ajax file and, if true, run a different function.

Comment: well, no, ajax is client-side, it sends an http request to the server much like the browser does when you navigate to a web page. it then returns plain text that gets sent to the ajax callback. so... the php needs to write something to the output in the same way you send html back for a normal page.

Comment: @KevinB thank you very much for your awnser. So what i am trying to do (basicly trying to have it return true or false) is impossible?

Comment: Concerning my question and what i am trying to achieve, is there anyone who can tell me if what i am trying to do is impossible or not and if so, please point me to the right direction on how to achieve this? My questions get downvoted while i am here to learn. It takes the fun out of learning how to code and being on Stackoverflow

Comment: Did you have some states on the notifications, for example: readed and unreaded?...it makes a lot of more sense if you instead of `ToF` return a json response from the server(see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) with all the unread notifications for that specific user...

Comment: @Hackerman Thank you for your awnser. I have made a different (working) ajax file which sends a screen notification and also sets 'sent' to 1 afterwards so it always gets the right 'row' from the database

Comment: Ok, so what do you want to accomplish is possible, but you need to add to your php script the following line `echo json_encode($checkmes);` just after your else statement....to check if it is working you need to put a `console.log(data)` on the body of your `$get` call...

Comment: It seems like you are trying to do this the hard way. I would suggest using Websockets or ServerSentEvents to do this. What you are doing is called "long polling" and is the old way of doing things and also eats up resources for no good reason. I havent done PHP in a while but im sure there are libraries to help you if you dont want to do it your self. SSE is a simple spec to implement.

Comment: @Hackerman thank you again. I really am new at javascript so should i replace a line or just add it? and if you have the time for it (otherwise i will look it up online, but maybe it helps somebody else too) what does console.log(date) do exactly?

Comment: `console.log(data)` should write the server response in your developer console(F12 on Chrome)...it is useful for debugging your ajax call(also you can use the Network tab to check the ajax request-response).

Comment: @Hackerman thank you for taking the time to teach me. Happiest girl on earth here:) it's not working yet, but i hope i'll get it working in a bit

Comment: @JohnS Thank you for teaching me something new. I will certainly read up on Websockets and SSE. I kind of re-invented something that's already age old...

Comment: I am glad to help you @Aurora; I started the same as you do, so don't worry, feel free to ask me any question(also you just need to add those lines :) )

Comment: @Hackerman thank you again! Maybe a weird question to ask, but is there a way on this forum people can 'connect' so you can keep in touch?

Comment: This is my personal email address: robert.rozas.n@gmail.com... Cheers :)

Comment: @Hackerman i have added you in my contacts and, of course, i will e-mail you :)

Comment: @Hackerman should i also add JSON_PRETTY_PRINT as in `echo json_encode($checkmes,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`?

Comment: It is optional....you can just write: `echo json_encode($checkmes);`

Comment: @Hackerman thank you again. Maybe another weird request. Could you please post the/your awnser with the code(if i'm not asking too much)? So i can mark your awnser as right when i get it working so you get the points added. Because you helped me out on solving my specific question most

Comment: I am going to post a full answer when i get home :)

Comment: @Hackerman i will await your awnser and as prommised, mark it:)

Comment: @Aurora Glad I could help. Things are always changing in this industry. That is one of my favorite parts. The other is communities like this. Dont discount your work on this though, you still learned something.

Comment: @JohnS For me learning how to code is a life changer. I was in flightschool to become a pilot. I got hit by a drunk driver, which ended my passion of flying. Since i've started learning how to code, for me, i finally got this huge passion for something i truely love back into my life :). And i absolutely love this community

Comment: @Hackerman i'm still doing something wrong. it gives an error saying checkmes is undefined. Really hoping for your awnser.

Comment: @Hackerman thank you so much for taking the time to help me. The script is running, but it keeps on running even after sent is set to 1 afterwards. But doesn't `if(data)` always return true? because even if `$messages` is false, it always contains data?

Comment: @Hackerman I have been trying to get it to work but it keeps calling refreshChat. I changed the javascript to 
`function checkMessages() {
  var myUrl = "'.$system->getDomain().'";
  myUrl + "/ajax/checkMessages.php";
  $.get(myUrl, function(data) {
   var mess = JSON.parse(data);
  });
   if(mess == "true"){
         refreshChat();
   }
}` but i can't get it to work. just wanted to ask if i am on the right track...

Comment: Check your email inbox :)

Comment: @Hackerman and you check yours :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make a few changes on your php script:

```
$user = $system->getUserInfo($_SESSION['user_id']);
$message = false;
$checkmes = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(1) AS CNTMESSAGES FROM notifications WHERE receiver_id='".$user."' AND sent='0'");
$checkmes = $checkmes->fetch_object();
//check the count value
if($checkmes->CNTMESSAGES > 0) {
   $message= true;
}
//Json response
echo json_encode($message);
```

And in your Javascript:

```
function checkMessages() {
  var myUrl = '<?php echo $system->getDomain(); ?>';
  myUrl + = '/ajax/checkMessages.php';
  $.get(myUrl, function(data){
      if(data){
         refreshChat();
      }
  });
 }

 window.setInterval(function(){
     checkMessages();
 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//checkMessages.php
$user = $system->getUserInfo($_SESSION['user_id']);

$checkmes = $db->query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE receiver_id='".$user."' AND sent='0'");

$checkmes = $checkmes->fetch_object();

if(!empty($checkmes)) {
    echo true;
}else{
    echo false;
}

//javascript
function checkMessages() {
    $.get($system->getDomain()+'/ajax/checkMessages.php', function(data){ 
        if(data == 'true'){
            refreshChat();
        }
    });
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    checkMessages();
}, 1000);
```

//assuming checkMessages.php is a different file

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, in order to be able to get the variable `$checkmes` you MUST make an `echo` in your php so that your AJAX request can read your data (i.e. whether it is true or false), like so:

```
$user = $system->getUserInfo($_SESSION['user_id']);

$checkmes = $db->query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE receiver_id='".$user."' AND sent='0'");
$checkmes = $checkmes->fetch_object();

if(!empty($checkmes)) {
    $checkmes = true;
} else{
    $checkmes = false;
}

echo $checkmes;
```

Then, as @u_mulder noticed your php string concatenation seems somewhat incorrect as well as there is no `echo`, make also sure that you are using php tags, I'd propose you something like this:

```
function checkMessages() {
    $.get("<?php echo $system->getDomain().'/ajax/checkMessages.php' ?>", function(checkmes) {
    // Here checkmes is a JavaScript variable and contains the data echoed from checkMessages.php
    if (checkmes == "true") {
        refreshChat();
    }
}); 

window.setInterval(function(){
  checkMessages();
}, 1000);
```